# Only way to edit CV is to "Create my CV"

Tags: feature-request, jobs

If I view my CV through the public URL, and notice a mistake, as far as I can tell, the only way to edit it is to navigate to the root careers page, and then click on the (now misleading) "Create my CV" page, even if I'm still logged in to the careers site.

Since the site knows I'm logged in and knows I'm me, there could be an "Edit" button at the top of the link?

Failing that, the "Create my CV" button should be renamed "Edit my CV" if a CV has been started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can click on your Name at the top of the screen to go to the menu where you can edit.

Comment: OK -- I see that works, and the linke there is "edit."

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the logo will also take you to the cv menu as well, once you've created a CV.

Comment: For me, clicking the logo takes me to the site homepage: http://www.marginalrevolution.com/marginalrevolution/2009/10/what-ive-been-reading-1.html, from which I can click the "Create..." button.